# В IE не работает classList.toggle

Tags: javascript

В ие 7 не работает функция classList.toggle. кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим? есть какой-нибудь хак? (пишу на чистом js)

```
function selectDate(){
    this.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

полный код [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/fwxuf5ea/31/)

уточняю вопрос. знаю что старые ие не поддерживают эти функции/методы. вопрос в том, как можно это обойти?

Comment: Вы не поверите, но это все потому, что IE7 не поддерживает `Element.classList` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: да вы что?! не может быть!

Comment: Если вы итак это знаете, то зачем спрашивать сталкивался ли кто-то с этим?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В IE7 вы можете работать напрямую со свойством `Element.className`. Например вот так:

```
function selectDate(){
    var re = /\bactive\b/;
    if (re.test(this.className)) {
        this.className = this.className.replace(re, '');
    } else {
        this.className += ' active';
    }
}
```

А еще в IE7 есть тонкость с определением обработчиков событий. Мало того, что события имеют префикс `on`, так еще и сам элемент не передается в качестве объекта `this`. Приведу один из вариантов подключения обработчика:

```
var div = document.getElementById('test');

if (div.addEventListener) {
    div.addEventListener('click', toggleActive);
} else if(div.attachEvent) {
    div.attachEvent('onclick', function() {
        toggleActive.apply(div, arguments);
    });
}
```

Comment: что такое `/\bactive\b/`  ?

Comment: Регулярное выражение, соответствующее строке `active` с граничными символами по краям

Comment: в ие7 не работает((

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, А вы уверены, что не работает именно приведенный код, а не JSFiddle?) Что в консоли браузера?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, как я и предполагал, `className` работает. А проблема в том, что вы не учитываете специфику IE при подключении обработчика! Обновил ответ

Comment: я уже применила attachEvent для выбора элемента вот код http://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/fwxuf5ea/31/

но пока не поняла как переписать код с classList.toggle

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, еще раз: как переписать код для `classList.toggle` я показал в первом блоке кода, а как правильно использовать `attachEvent` -- во втором блоке. Что касается JSFiddle, то его новая версия **не работает** в IE7. Тестировать код для IE7 в JSFiddle **бессмысленно**!